# how can i use only custom font without family font system on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, font-family, custom-font

I use [CLImageEditor this link](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor), but in the fonts picker it displays the system fonts, I do not want to display it, Because it contains strangely repetitive NewRoman fonts, I have custom fonts, I added to my project and appears in the fonts picker,Custom font that I've added also show with system fonts, how can I hide the system fonts or select specific fonts only, where most of the fonts are similar I do not want to fill font picker withe many fonts.

this code on CLFontPickerView.m :

```
+ (NSArray*)allFontList
{
    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
        for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]){
            [list addObject:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:kCLFontPickerViewConstantFontSize]];
        }
    }
    
    return [list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fontName" ascending:YES]]];
}
```

or you can see it full code from [this link](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor/tree/master/OptionalImageTools/CLTextTool)

Comment: Are there any suggestions or answers to this question?

Comment: please help me , i can't found any answer for objective c code